# Why are entries deleted in both cases?

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

#### Brief

Hello everyone! I'm starter in javascript. I use Laravel + DataTables in my project. Now I use [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) instead of default confirms javascript.

#### Code

Here I call my javascript method:

```
<a href="#" onclick="deleteData('.$contact->id.')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
   <span>Delete</span>
</a>
```

Here my javascript function:

```
function deleteData(id){
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{url('contact')}}" + '/' + id,
      type: "POST",
      data: {'_method' : 'DELETE', '_token' : csrf_token},
      success: function(data){
        contacts.ajax.reload();
        swal({
          title: 'Success!',
          text: 'Data has been deleted!',
          type: 'success',
          timer: '1500'
        })
      },
      error: function(){
        swal({
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Something went wrong!',
          type: 'error',
          timer: '1500'
        })
      }
    });
  });
}
```

When I'll click to delete button:

[image]

Showing confirm model:

[image]

Then I'll click to **cancel** button. But after click to cancel button deleted data from database. And why are entries deleted in both cases?

Comment: In the then function after swal you need to check if ok or cancel was pressed and only delete stuff if ok was pressed.  Have a look at the examples under “using promises” [here](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides)

Comment: I seen documentation @James but I do not understand what to check here for clicking. How do I check which button was pressed? In javascript have function `button = confirm('Confirm message!')` and can use it `if(button == true)` but in sweetalerts I can't use check clicked button.

Comment: The way you use, `then` is wrong, it basically says, whenever the sweetAlert is displayed or finished showing, then delete the data from the server, you have to check whether the button was pressed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to check the result of resolved promise:

```js
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function(result){
  

  if (result.value) {
    // perform the AJAX request
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Related example from the official docs: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#dismiss-handle

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my javascript code @Limon Monte